# Angular2: How to access index.html querystring in App Component

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 Development.

I have a requirment where i need to call Angular2 Web site from my ASP.Net Web site. While calling Angular2 website (localhost:4200\index.html), will pass querystring like as below 
**localhost:4200\index.html?UserID=Chandra**

Now my Question is.

How to get **UserId** querystring value into **App Component (i.e. BootStrap Compoent) or any other component**.

Please help me witht this.

**Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters) are pretty decent on this if you haven't looked at them.  The short answer is, to access query parameters from the a component, you'll need to use the `ActivatedRoute`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

....

export class MyComponent {

    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams =>
       //do something with queryParams['UserID']
     );
   }

}
```

The router will hold both route params and query params.  They are treated separately.  `Subscribe` to the `queryParams` to access those parameters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked for me. But without <router-outlet>
  </router-outlet> statement , its throwing error.