# How to manage HTML5 route fallback with parameter for Angular SPA with ASP.NET Core in Startup.cs?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, routes, single-page-application, fallback

I was searching, but did not manage finding any answer, maybe here someone smart knows what to do. I have Angular SPA, with ASP.NET Core back-end. In Angular I dont want to use `Hash Bang Routes`. But I have no idea how to configure routing, to be able to refresh or enter a SPA component page with a parameter. For example: `somewebsite.com/a5eccbd9 //where a5eccbd9 is a parameter`.

Examples closest to my problem, but routing just to `index.html` of the SPA.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61275033

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/aug/07/handling-html5-client-route-fallbacks-in-aspnet-core#Letting-ASP.NET-Core-Handle-Client-Side-Routes

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jul/12/Handling-SPA-Fallback-Paths-in-a-Generic-ASPNET-Core-Server#handling-fallbacks-with-built-in-endpoints-and-route-processing

But after being routed to the file, what next to do with parameter and being redirected to the correct component? My Angular routing:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
...
  {
    path: '',
    component: FormComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: FormComponent,
  },
...
];
```

And in `index.html` I have: `<base href="/" />`

And in my dead end I have no idea how to make back-end redirecting me properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually **fallback routing** for the Angular was easier than I expected. In the back-end I just needed to add end-point mapping:

```js
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/{id}", "/index.html"); //<- added
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/", "/index.html");
            });
```

And from now on after GET request: `somewebsite.com/a5eccbd9` ASP.NET Core redirects it to the Angular SPA's `index.html`, and over there Angular's routing deal with that oryginal request by its own routing `path: ':id',`.

I was also considering solution from here: [Angular2: How to access index.html querystring in App Component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43257272) where from ASP.NET Core I wanted to redirect it to: `index.html?id={id}`, and in main app component to catch `id`, but Angular appeared to be smarter than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
const routes: Routes = [
...
  {
    path: '',
    component: FormComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '/:id',
    component: FormComponent,
  },
...
];
```

In your component.ts, you can get the id by call use this on ngOnInit method :

```html
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  
ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but already I am using `this.route.snapshot.params.id`, and with `path: '/:id',` I receive an error: `Invalid configuration of route '/:id': path cannot start with a slash`. Anyway, the main problem is that on SPA **fallback** the client looses the rooting and I just receive **404**.

Comment: sorry, still use ':id', that's correct, and then to get the id value, just use this.route.snapshot.params.id. It should work :)